# Jquery DataTables - Joining tables with lookup table

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I have a lookup (or link) table `learning_event_presentation_lookup`:

```
+---------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| learning_event_presentation_lookup_pk | learning_event_fk | presentation_fk |
+---------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

This is to facilitate joining tables `learning_event` and `presentation`.

I need to use that table in a join in the following code.

Currently I'm getting the error:

*DataTables warning: table id=learning_event_table - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'learning_event'*

```
$( '#learning_event_table' ).DataTable( {
                ajax: "program_data/learning_event_data.php",
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                columns: [ {
                    data: "learning_event.learning_event_name"
                }, {
                    data: "learning_event.learning_event_outcome"
                }, {
                    data: "rdb_group.rdb_group_name"
                }, {
                    data: "presentation.presentation_name"
                }, {
                    data: "rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_name"
                } ],
                select: {
                    style: 'os',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                },
                buttons: [ {
                    extend: "create",
                    editor: editor
                }, {
                    extend: "edit",
                    editor: editor
                }, {
                    extend: "remove",
                    editor: editor
                } ]
            } );
```

and

```
Editor::inst( $db2, 'learning_event', 'learning_event_pk' )   
    ->field(
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.learning_event_name' ),
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.learning_event_outcome' ),
    Field::inst( 'presentation.presentation_name' ),
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.rdb_group_fk' )
            ->options( Options::inst()
                ->table( 'rdb_group' )
                ->value( 'rdb_group_pk' )
                ->label( 'rdb_group_name' )
            )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'rdb_group.rdb_group_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk' )
            ->options( Options::inst()
                ->table( 'rotation_discipline_block' )
                ->value( 'rotation_discipline_block_pk' )
                ->label( 'rotation_discipline_block_name' )
            )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dbValues' ),
        Field::inst( 'rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_name' )

    )
    ->leftJoin( 'rdb_group', 'rdb_group.rdb_group_pk', '=', 'learning_event.rdb_group_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'rotation_discipline_block', 'rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_pk', '=', 'learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'presentation', 'presentation.presentation_pk', '=', 'learning_event_presentation_lookup.presentation_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'learning_event', 'learning_event.learning_event_pk', '=', 'learning_event_presentation_lookup.learning_event_fk' )
    ->process($_POST)
    ->json();
```

Comment: If you make that as a sql you can figure it out. It says that `learning_event` is joined twice with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I looked at the documenation on using a linked table at:

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/joinLinkTable.html

So now I have the following which is not producing any errors and working correctly. Not exactly intuitive doing the joins in the dataTables format though...

```
Editor::inst( $db2, 'learning_event', 'learning_event_pk' )   
    ->field(
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.learning_event_name' ),
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.learning_event_outcome' ),
    Field::inst( 'presentation.presentation_name' ),
     Field::inst( 'learning_event.rdb_group_fk' )
            ->options( Options::inst()
                ->table( 'rdb_group' )
                ->value( 'rdb_group_pk' )
                ->label( 'rdb_group_name' )
            )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'rdb_group.rdb_group_name' ),
        Field::inst( 'learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk' )
            ->options( Options::inst()
                ->table( 'rotation_discipline_block' )
                ->value( 'rotation_discipline_block_pk' )
                ->label( 'rotation_discipline_block_name' )
            )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dbValues' ),
        Field::inst( 'rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_name' )

    )
    ->leftJoin( 'rdb_group', 'rdb_group.rdb_group_pk', '=', 'learning_event.rdb_group_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'rotation_discipline_block', 'rotation_discipline_block.rotation_discipline_block_pk', '=', 'learning_event.rotation_discipline_block_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'learning_event_presentation_lookup', 'learning_event.learning_event_pk', '=', 'learning_event_presentation_lookup.learning_event_fk' )
    ->leftJoin( 'presentation', 'learning_event_presentation_lookup.presentation_fk', '=', 'presentation.presentation_pk' )
    ->process($_POST)
    ->json();
```